# Getting wrong month in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js included through RequireJS. When I call `Moment().month()`, instead of number 11 I always get number 10. Any ideas how can this happen?

Comment: Isn't [january month 0](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/)? `Note: Months are zero indexed, so January is month 0.`

Comment: in javascript's Date, months are counted 0-11. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Try Moment().format("MM")

Comment: You can always use the .add method to account for the zero index .add(1, 'M')

Comment: @JeremyHamm That doesn't work for December. `moment.parseZone('12/01/2018','MM/DD/YYYY').add({M:1}).month()`

Comment: Thank you @RenatoGama : it returns the correct month number, starting from one.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

According to Moment.js [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month), 'month' uses an array and the indices of an array are zero-based. Therefore, January is set to '0' and December is set to '11'.

For example, `moment().month('November');` prints '10'.

Comment: Just a clarification. 0-based indexing of the months is a feature that Moment.js inherits from Javascript. See the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) at par.15.9.1.4 for further details.

Comment: Almost feels like they should expose it as 1-12 for the sake of intuitive use in lieu of the the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: by this logic why arent year, date, hours and minutes zero based?(snark, sorry)

Comment: They actually claim month is not zero based: 
M MM 1..12 Month number

Comment: working link to ECMAScript month spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.4

Comment: We should create a dedicated web page that states the total dev time wasted by this.

Answer (score 1):

moment().month gets or sets the month and accepts numbers from 0 to 11. Key here is that index starts at 0, not 1. The below code will work as a solution for this question.

```
{Moment(yourDate).month(Moment(yourDate).month()-1).format("MMMM Do YYYY")}
```

The above code for 8/30/2022 will show August 30th 2022.

```
{Moment(yourDate).month(Moment(yourDate).month()-1).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
```

The above code for 8/30/2022 will show 08-30-2022.

```
{Moment(yourDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
```

The above code for 8/30/2022 will show 09-30-2022.