# Why are month in moment js starting from index 0?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I know [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20094812/14441298) and there is an issue also on [GitHub](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4346) as well but is there any logical reason for why the months in moment js starting from index 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is the javascript date month index 0-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828883/why-is-the-javascript-date-month-index-0-based)

Comment: Probably because the JS Date function also does this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor

Comment: It is defined in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.4)

Comment: But then days also should have this logic right?

Comment: @Singh no? Why would they. Having zero based months has a *long* history from at least back in C. Probably from before. It makes it easier to make something like (in JS) `monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", /* etc */]; monthNames[date.getMonth()]` to turn them to words. Same thing with week days. Otherwise, you need to either make an empty slot in the array (more memory) or do some more arithmetic with the month number (more CPU). Not relevant nowadays but it's an artefact from the past. Same thing can be observed with week days. There is no reason to need zero based month days.

Answer (score 0):

0-based indexing of the months is a feature that Moment.js inherits from Javascript.